# ClientCallStreamObserver isReady never returns true

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I'm making an input stream rate meter. It is basically a service that exposes a request stream call and counts how many messages per second it can handle.

As the client is totally async when it comes to sending messages, I use the ClientCallStreamObserver to start sending messages just when the stream is ready, to avoid memory overflow.

The client code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ManagedChannel channel =  ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("server", 4242).usePlaintext(true).build();
    ServerGrpc.ServerStub asyncStub = ServerGrpc.newStub(channel);


    StreamObserver<MarketDataOuterClass.Trade> inputStream = asyncStub.reportNewTradeStream(new StreamObserver<Empty>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Empty empty) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            logger.info("on error response stream");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            logger.info("on completed response stream");
        }
    });

    final ClientCallStreamObserver<MarketDataOuterClass.Trade> clientCallObserver = (ClientCallStreamObserver<MarketDataOuterClass.Trade>) inputStream;

    while (!clientCallObserver.isReady()) {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        logger.info("stream not ready yet");
    }

    counter.setLastTic(System.nanoTime());

    while (true) {
        counter.inc();
        if (counter.getCounter() % 15000 == 0 ) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            double rate = (double) NANOSEC_TO_SEC * counter.getCounter() / (now - counter.getLastTic());
            logger.info("rate: " + rate + " msgs per sec");
            counter.clear();
            counter.setLastTic(now);
        }
        inputStream.onNext(createRandomTrade());
    }
}
```

My observation loop over isReady is never ending.

OBS: I'm using kubernetes cluster to serve my test, the server is receiving the call and returning a StreamObserver implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isReady` should eventually return `true`, as long as the RPC doesn't error/complete immediately. But the code is not observing flow control properly.

After each call to `onNext()` to send a request `isReady()` could begin returning `false`. Your `while (true)` loop should instead have the `isReady()` check at the beginning of each iteration.

Instead of polling, it is better to call `serverCallObserver.setOnReadyHandler(yourRunnable)` to be notified when the call is ready to send. Note that you should still check `isReady()` within `yourRunnable` as there can be spurious/out-of-date notifications.

Comment: changing the verification to right before sending a message did work. setOnReadyHandler looks better, will try it.

Comment: @FelipeJun, you will still need to block the main() until the RPC completes. For something like the code you showed, the easiest thing would be to `channel.shutdown()` after starting the RPC and then `channel.awaitTerminated()`. Once the RPC completes, then channel will become terminated and `awaitTerminated()` will return.